# dbt pipeline call from Azure Data Factory using Azure Container Instance with a variable command

Tags: azure-functions, azure-container-instances, dbt, azure-data-factory

I'm looking to call dbt in a child pipeline from Azure Data Factory.
Looking at the following project on GitHub it's been done before.
https://gitlab.com/hashmapinc/oss/dbtonazure

What I would like to do though is pass a parametrised call from the Data Factory Web Activity so instead of having an Environment Variable in an Azure Containerised Instance and having to have a separate ACI for each dbt command I'd like to run I can pass a variable command to dbt.

e.g.
Main pipeline runs and passes a variable "a".
dbt runs
dbt run --select a

Main pipeline runs and passes a variable "b".
dbt runs
dbt run --select b

I'm leaning to writing an Azure Function to accept incoming messages, where the message is the command.

Thanks,
Dan